# SQL Join Statement

Tags: sql, select, join

I have the following SQL SELECT statement

```
SELECT bar_id, bar_name, town_name, advert_text     
FROM bar, towns, baradverts
WHERE town_id = town_id_fk
AND bar_id = bar_id_fk
```

My problem is that since not every bar has an advert in table "baradverts", these bars are not coming up in the results. In other words I need a NULL for those bars that do not have an advert string.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a 'left outer join'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell which column goes with which table, but I think this is what you are looking for. If you post your schema that would help.

```
SELECT bar_id, bar_name, town_name, advert_text      
FROM bar b
inner join towns t on t.town_id = b.town_id_fk 
left outer join baradverts ba on t.town_id = ba.town_id_fk 
    AND b.bar_id = ba.bar_id_fk
```

Answer (score 0):

you may find this helpful reading:

[Understanding SQL Joins](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/)